# python bs4 check tag exist or not in parents tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i am self learning python in a few months, I want to write the code for listing a table for monitor price in the market, here with the code, and i want to wirte a new column for display the item has been sold.

i check the html as follow

```
<div class="col_2">
 <span class="trade_title">
  <span class="sell">
   售
  </span>
  Sapphire NITRO+ AMD Radeon™ RX 6900 XT SE
 </span>
 <div class="trade_info">
  <div class="meta_item hidden-xs">
   <span style="color: #999; font-size: 13px;">
    shermanc999
   </span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

the above code is not sell yet.

```
<div class="col_2">
 <div>
  <span class="item_tag confirmed">
   <fa fa-deal"="">
    交易完成
   </fa>
  </span>
 </div>
 <span class="trade_title">
  <span class="sell">
   售
  </span>
  INNO3D Geforce gtx 1060 6GB
 </span>
 <div class="trade_info">
  <div class="meta_item hidden-xs">
   <span style="color: red; font-size: 9px;line-height: 15px; display: inline-block; background-color: #ff4400; color: #fff; margin-right: 5px; padding: 0px 5px; border-radius: 3px;">
    新會員
   </span>
   <span style="color: #999; font-size: 13px;">
    Woody_TSO
   </span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

this code has been sold.

```
    for class_up_level in soup.find_all(class_= "col_2"):
        
        if 'item_tag confirmed' in class_up_level:
            
            item_tag_list.append('completed')
        else:
            item_tag_list.append('progress')
```

i have try to add above code in the for loop, but result show all are progress.

[completed photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2PYR.png)

```
import urllib.request as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import re
import datetime

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)
pd.set_option("display.width", None)

id_list= ['84']#,'20']
class_list = ['trade_title','price','misc','item_tag confirmed','clearfix']
title_list, price_list, date_list, view_list, link_list, type_list, model_list, item_tag_list = [],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]

model_re = re.compile(r'[0-9]{3,4}')
view_times_re = re.compile(r"(?P<time>\d+\D+)\D{3}(?P<view>\d+)\D+")

def has_class_but_no_id(tag):
    return tag.has_attr('class') and not tag.has_attr('id')

#sibling_soup.c.previous_sibling

for id_no in id_list:
    id_name = 'Display Card' if id_no == '84' else 'Computer'
    for i in range(1,2):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(f'Loading Page {i} . . .')
        url = 'https://www.dcfever.com/trading/listing.php?id='+ id_no + 'order=new&type=used&page='+str(i)
        request=req.Request(url, headers={"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36"})
        with req.urlopen(request) as response:
            data=response.read().decode("utf-8")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

        for col_2 in soup.find_all(class_= "col_2"):
            print(col_2.prettify())
        #for sibling in soup.find(class_= "trade_title").previous_siblings:
        #    print(repr(sibling))
        
        # for tag in soup.find_all(class_= "item_tag confirmed"):

        # print(soup.prettify())
        sibling_trade_title = soup.find(class_= "trade_title")

        # for sibling in sibling_col_2:
        # for sibling in sibling_trade_title.previous_siblings:

            # print(repr(sibling))
        #     print(repr(sibling))
        # soup.find_all(class_= "item_tag confirmed")

        for class_up_level in soup.find_all(class_= "col_2"):
            
            if 'item_tag confirmed' in class_up_level:
                
                item_tag_list.append('completed')
            else:
                item_tag_list.append('progress')



        for class_title in class_list[0:4]:      
            for data in soup.find_all(class_= class_title):

                data = data.get_text()
                
                if class_title == 'trade_title':
                    title_list.append(data)
                    #model_list = [model_re.search(data).group(0) if model_re.search(data) == True else "N"]
                    #print(model_list)
                    if model_re.search(data):
                        model_list.append(model_re.search(data).group(0))
                    else:
                        model_list.append('N') 

                if class_title == 'price':
                    try:
                        data = np.float64(data.strip().replace('&nbsp;', '').replace('HK$', '').replace(',', '').replace('價錢: 請洽詢我','0').replace('\xa0', ''))
                    except ValueError:
                        data = data
                    
                    price_list.append(data)
                    #(int(cells[2].text.strip().replace('$', '').replace(',', '')))
                    #df["Numbers"] = [float(str(i).replace(",", "")) for i in df["Numbers"]]

                if class_title == 'misc':                                      
                    date_list.append(view_times_re.search(data).group("time"))
                    view_list.append(int(view_times_re.search(data).group("view")))




                
                

        for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True, class_='clearfix'):
            link = (link.get('href'))
            link = 'https://www.dcfever.com/trading/'+str(link)
            link_list.append(link)
            type_list.append(id_name)         
        
      







def output_to_excel():
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Title" : title_list,
                    'Model' : model_list,
                    "Price" : price_list,
                    "Misc" : date_list,
                    "View" : view_list,
                    'Link' : link_list,
                    "Type": type_list,
                    'Item Tag' : item_tag_list
                    })

    print("Loaded all pages, Writing data in excel...")
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f'DcFever {datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S")}.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')    
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='DcFever', index=False)    
    for column in df:
        column_length = max(df[column].astype(str).map(len).max(), len(column))
        col_idx = df.columns.get_loc(column)
        writer.sheets['DcFever'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_length)
    writer.save()
    #writer.close()
    print("Saved excel. Program Completed.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause it is a BeautifulSoup object simply try to find the classes:

```
if class_up_level.find(class_='item_tag confirmed'):
    item_tag_list.append('completed')
else:
   item_tag_list.append('progress')
```

or with `css selectors`:

```
for class_up_level in soup.select('.col_2'):
    item_tag_list.append('completed')
else:
   item_tag_list.append('progress')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for data in soup.find_all(class_= 'col_2'):
    if data.find(class_= 'trade_title').previous_sibling != None:
        item_tag_list.append(data.find(class_='item_tag confirmed').get_text())                
    else: 
        item_tag_list.append('progress')
```

Finally use above code for solve my problem
Thanks your help.

Comment: You should also add some explanation of the answer, see how do I write a good answer [answer].